# Failed to program FILTER chain: iptables failed

Tags: iptables, docker, docker-compose

OS: Ubuntu Server edition (headless) 20.04 LTS.

Attempting to ge a makemkv container running: https://hub.docker.com/r/jlesage/makemkv

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  makemkv:
    image: jlesage/makemkv
    ports:
      - "5800:5800"
    volumes:
      - "/config:/config:rw"
      - "/storage:/storage:ro"
      - "/output:/output:rw"
    devices:
      - "/dev/sr0:/dev/sr0"
     # - "/dev/sg2:/dev/sg2"
```

Port 5800 is open in iptables:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5800 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 5800 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Command: `sudo docker compose up -d`

Result:

```
[+] Running 0/0
 ⠿ Network makemkv_default  Error                                                                                                            0.0s
failed to create network makemkv_default: Error response from daemon: Failed to program FILTER chain: iptables failed: iptables --wait -I FORWARD -o br-48dd0ff8ab37 -j DOCKER: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): Couldn't load target `DOCKER':No such file or directory
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the container, and the related network and then ran this: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Then I was able to run the following command and all worked: `sudo docker compose up -d`